# How should I time highlighting of text with audio for a karaoke like application in javaFx

Tags: java, audio, synchronization, javafx, javafx-2

I am building an JavaFx application in which I have a text file and a audio mp3 file which reads it out. When I play the audio using [MediaPlayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html) object and display the text from the text file. Is there any way to highlight each word as they are being played ? I know how subtitles are encoded and kept in a separated file but here it has to be done for each word. i.e. each word on the text file should have metadata how long it should be kept highlighted offset from the beginning of the mp3 file.

Another way is to calculate using a formula and length of text and audio file and find approximate time each world should be kept highlighted but this cam make highlighting out of sync.

Is there any standard way or standard metadata format in which I can encode the information how much time a word should be kept highlighted as the narration audio plays ?

Comment: I don't think that this is related to JavaFX. One approach which I saw in other applications was that you initially tap space whenever a word begins. You could then store this information.

Comment: @user510083 Yes It is generic about question about the teqnique. I was hoping there would be some easier way/api in javaFx. Can you explain what information do you think should I store ? The time stamp of beginning of each word ?

Comment: Either that, or just a list of ms + a seperate list of words (which both should have the same no of elements ;)). That way the list of words could be a textfile that looks like a lyric from the web.. one line in the textfile is one displayed line in karaoke-mode.

Comment: Are you still working on it?Please Reply, i am on same thing, almost done!

Comment: @joeyrohan Hey thanks for commenting ! I scoped out this in my V1 release but it would be great if I can do it v2. Would you share how did you achieve this ?

Comment: @NeilGhosh yeah sure!what was your logic for highlighting the words?Mine is bit complex :/

Comment: @NeilGhosh have you tried?

Comment: @joeyrohan Thanks for sharing the strategy , I am yet to start coding for V2 , so I am open to all approaches

Answer (score 0):

I used straight logic for this. This stuff cannot be automatic (can be, but requires endless effort), so first you need to ask user to set the timings. Display the .txt file, and play the song in background. With the help of this, user highlights the words, and now you obtain the timings with the help of System.Current time in millisecs, and store the timings in an array or a list. When it is done, now you play the karaoke. Highlight the words, as per the timings.The words will get highlighted on the press of ESC key. Change the .txt file as per your need.
Please ignore my bad style of coding :p

Here is a demo of that in Swing:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.*;


public class newh extends JFrame
                       implements DocumentListener {
 public static int[] arry=new int[1000];

static int first=0,last=0,scan=0,acount=0;int flag=1,point=0,j=0;long value,stat;
private JTextField entry;private boolean fir=true;
private JLabel jLabel1;
private JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private JLabel status;
private JTextArea textArea;
private  JFrame frame;
long start;
final static Color  HILIT_COLOR = Color.YELLOW;
final static Color  ERROR_COLOR = Color.PINK;
final static String CANCEL_ACTION = "cancel-search";
final static String SMALL_ICON = "cancel-search";
final Color entryBg;
final Highlighter hilit;
final Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter;
private long start2;
JButton startButton;


public newh() throws FileNotFoundException {
    initComponents();
String[] a=new String[1000];
    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("lyri.txt");
    try {
    textArea.read(new InputStreamReader(in), null);

    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }


   hilit = new DefaultHighlighter();
    painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(HILIT_COLOR);
    textArea.setHighlighter(hilit);

    entryBg = entry.getBackground();
    entry.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);

   InputMap im = entry.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
    ActionMap am = entry.getActionMap();

     im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESCAPE"), CANCEL_ACTION);
   am.put(CANCEL_ACTION, new CancelAction());




  }




/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 */

  private void initComponents() {

    entry = new JTextField();
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    status = new JLabel();
    jLabel1 = new JLabel();
    frame = new JFrame();


  setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("TextFieldDemo");

    textArea.setColumns(20);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setRows(5);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(textArea);
 final JFrame jar=new JFrame();

    jLabel1.setText("Enter text to search:");
startButton = new JButton("Start");jar.add(startButton);
jar.setVisible(true);jar.pack();
    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            try {
                ColoredTextTest.start();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(newh.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(newh.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
           setVisible(false);
           jar.setVisible(false);

            }
    });
    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);

//Create a parallel group for the horizontal axis
ParallelGroup hGroup = layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);

//Create a sequential and a parallel groups
SequentialGroup h1 = layout.createSequentialGroup();
ParallelGroup h2 = layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER);

//Add a container gap to the sequential group h1
h1.addContainerGap();

//Add a scroll pane and a label to the parallel group h2
h2.addComponent(jScrollPane1, GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 600, Short.MAX_VALUE);
h2.addComponent(status, GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 900, Short.MAX_VALUE);

//Create a sequential group h3
SequentialGroup h3 = layout.createSequentialGroup();
h3.addComponent(jLabel1);
h3.addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED);
h3.addComponent(entry, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 900, Short.MAX_VALUE);

//Add the group h3 to the group h2
h2.addGroup(h3);
//Add the group h2 to the group h1
    h1.addGroup(h2);

h1.addContainerGap();

//Add the group h1 to the hGroup
hGroup.addGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, h1);
//Create the horizontal group
layout.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup);


//Create a parallel group for the vertical axis
ParallelGroup vGroup = layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);
//Create a sequential group v1
SequentialGroup v1 = layout.createSequentialGroup();
//Add a container gap to the sequential group v1
v1.addContainerGap();
//Create a parallel group v2
ParallelGroup v2 = layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE);

v2.addComponent(jLabel1);
v2.addComponent(entry, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE);
//Add the group v2 tp the group v1

v1.addGroup(v2);
v1.addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED);
v1.addComponent(jScrollPane1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 900, Short.MAX_VALUE);
v1.addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED);
v1.addComponent(status);
v1.addContainerGap();

//Add the group v1 to the group vGroup
vGroup.addGroup(v1);

layout.setVerticalGroup(vGroup);
pack();
}

@SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
public void search() throws BadLocationException {

int i;
    start=System.currentTimeMillis();


    arry[point]=(int) (start - start2-10);
    point++;


    if(fir==true)
    {fir=false;point=0;}
    start2=start;



    String s = textArea.getText();

    char[] words=s.toCharArray();


    for(i=last;words[i]!=' '&&words[i]!='\n';i++,last=i)
    {

    }
  try {
           hilit.addHighlight(first, last, painter);

      last++;   first=last;

      } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(newh.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


  }

void message(String msg) {

 }

// DocumentListener methods

public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
   // search();
}

public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
   // search();
}

public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) throws BadLocationException {

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

class CancelAction extends AbstractAction {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        try {
            search();
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(newh.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
 }




 public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {
 start();


}
   public void setvisiblet()
{
setVisible(true);

}
public void setvisiblef()
{
setVisible(false);

}
public static void start()
{

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
            try {
                new newh().setVisible(true);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(newh.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
 }


}
class ColoredTextTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private String[] words=new String[1000];
private JScrollPane sc;
String sentence="";
int stringIndex = 0;
 int index = 0;
 Timer timer;
StyledDocument  doc;
/** Creates new form textdisplay */
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")

public ColoredTextTest() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    initComponents();
     doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
jTextPane1.setDocument(doc);
 javax.swing.text.Style style = jTextPane1.addStyle("Red", null);
StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.RED);



    File file = new File("lyri.txt");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
String line = null;
while( (line = br.readLine())!= null ){
sentence+=line;
sentence+='\n';
}

br.close();
int j=0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("lyri.txt"));
file = new File("lyri.txt");
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
while(input.hasNext()) {
words[j] = input.next(); System.out.println(words[j]);j++;words[j]=" ";j++;
}

jTextPane1.setText(sentence);


}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    setUndecorated(true);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(3, 3, 3, 3, new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 204)));
    jPanel1.setInheritsPopupMenu(true);

    jButton1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 0));
    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Virtual DJ", 0, 14));
    jButton1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 255));
    jButton1.setText("Back");
    jButton1.setOpaque(false);

    jButton2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 0));
    jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Virtual DJ", 0, 14));
    jButton2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 255));
    jButton2.setText("Pause");
    jButton2.setOpaque(false);

    jButton3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 0));
    jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Virtual DJ", 1, 14));
    jButton3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 255));
    jButton3.setText("Play");
    jButton3.setOpaque(false);
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 0));
    jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Virtual DJ", 0, 14));
    jButton4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 255));
    jButton4.setText("close");
    jButton4.setOpaque(false);
    jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jSeparator1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 255, 255));

    jTextPane1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    jTextPane1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
    jTextPane1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 255));
    jTextPane1.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(false);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextPane1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 93, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 101, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 114, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 611, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGap(23, 23, 23))
        .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 982, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 982, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 645, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    java.awt.Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setBounds((screenSize.width-988)/2, (screenSize.height-710)/2, 988, 710);
  }// </editor-fold>

 private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    setVisible(false);
}

 private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    this.sc=jScrollPane1;
    JScrollBar verticalScrollBar = sc.getVerticalScrollBar();
    JScrollBar horizontalScrollBar = sc.getHorizontalScrollBar();
    verticalScrollBar.setValue(verticalScrollBar.getMinimum());
    horizontalScrollBar.setValue(horizontalScrollBar.getMinimum());





 dotimer();
  }

 public void dotimer()
 {

 ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

             System.out.println("index"+stringIndex);
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(stringIndex, 1, jTextPane1.getStyle("Red"), true);

            stringIndex++;

                try {
                    if (stringIndex >= doc.getLength() || doc.getText(stringIndex, 1).equals(" ")|| doc.getText(stringIndex, 1).equals("\n")) {
                        index++;
                    }
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ColoredTextTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                if (index < 600) {

                    double delay = newh.arry[index];
                    timer.setDelay((int) (delay / words[index].length()));
                } else {
                    timer.stop();
                    System.err.println("Timer stopped");
                }

            }

    };
    timer = new Timer(newh.arry[index], actionListener);
    timer.setInitialDelay(0); System.out.println("done.........");
    timer.start();







 }
 public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException {
    start();

 }
 public static void start() throws InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException
 {
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                new ColoredTextTest().setVisible(true);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ColoredTextTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ColoredTextTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            ColoredTextTest y = null;
            try {
                y = new ColoredTextTest();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ColoredTextTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ColoredTextTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    });


   }

private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1;


}
```